# Limit what code can be executed when evaluating (eval()) user input for patchwork

Tags: r, security, shiny

I have implemented Patchwork into my Shiny Application, through which users can easily arrange multiple plots. Since the Syntax of Patchwork is that easy, I want to display a textInput to the user, through which they can issue patchwork commands as "A + B" or "(A | B) / C". In my code, this looks like this: `eval(parse(text = input$patchwork_text))`

This however poses a massive security risk, as any code can be executed by the user. Is there a good way to ensure, that the textInput is only used as intended? I don't want to give up the flexibility that it gives. Would something work to limit the input to a few symbols (+, /, |, (, ) ) and single, uppercase characters? I'm looking forward to any feedback :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is never a good idea to let users run code in a shiny session, but this is what I would do to check that only operations on objects that you want to allow are performed.

Note that this is just a start, please expand this function.

I was not sure, whether the names of the plot objects are given or not. If they are created on the fly then you would need to grab them and pass the names as strings into the `allowed_nms` argument. Otherwise we can just default to `LETTERS` as @Mikko points out in the comments.

In general I would advise to not work with strings (and regexs), but turn the string into a call object with `str2lang` and then we can use `all.vars()` and other functions to inspect the call.

```r
check_call <- function(inp_string, allowed_nms = LETTERS) {
  
  allowed_fns <- c("+", "-", "/", "(", "|", "&")
  
  inp_call <- str2lang(inp_string)
  
  all_nms <- all.vars(inp_call)
  all_sym <- all.names(inp_call)
  all_fns <- setdiff(all_sym, all_nms)
  
  if (any(!all_fns %in% allowed_fns)) {
    stop("This operation is not allowed")
  }
  
  if (!is.null(allowed_nms) && any(!all_nms %in% allowed_nms)) {
    stop("Not allowed object name.")
  }
}

check_call("(A | B) / C")

check_call("(A | B) / z")
#> Error in check_call("(A | B) / z"): Not allowed object name.

check_call("system('rm -rf /')", allowed_nms = c("A", "B"))
#> Error in check_call("system('rm -rf /')", allowed_nms = c("A", "B")): This operation is not allowed
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @MikkoMarttila It seems I missed the part with the single uppercase characters! Thanks for pointing that out. And a simple version might only use `all.names()`, but maybe he wants to let the user know whether the function or the object name throws the error and in that case the distinction might be helpful.

Comment: Yeah you're right -- I deleted my comment after realising variable names could be allowed as symbols but not as calls, so your more thorough checking is definitely warranted. Sorry to jump the gun!

Comment: This is great, thank you for your thourough answer! Will implement this right now :D
@TimTeaFan would I go wrong if I added a "return(inp_call)" after the last if? Then I could possibly throw this directly into the eval() (and add some error handling later on).

Comment: oh and to answer your question cocerning the names, I am just using single uppercase characters to keep the Syntax simple for the user, so allowed_nms = LETTERS is perfect. But it's great to have that as an option for the next time this issue comes up.

Comment: @Jan you can just return `inp_call` and call `eval()` it. Probably you are a reactive context, then I would first check the string and if it throws an error make it show a nice error msg instead of the arranged plots.

Comment: Yeah that's what I had in mind, thank you for the clarification!